# Is it possible to disable mouse resizing in tmux without disabling mouse mode?

Tags: tmux

Pre tmux-2.1 I had granular control of my mouse. One feature I always hated was resizing panes via mouse (`mouse-resize-pane`), it was slow and often felt more like a bug than a feature (i.e. I try to select text and accidentally resize the pane).

Since 2.1 rework, the authors of TMUX consolidated all mouse features into 1 (`set -g mouse on`). The authors feel like they have made an improvement, but to me the new all-or-nothing mode is actually a step back. I ignored it for a while because I don't use the mouse often enough, but now that this "feature" has bitten me several times in the last few months, I wanted to see if there is a way to disable it (without disabling mouse mode altogether, because I still like using mouse-wheel to scroll and select text via mouse). Is there a way to achieve this in modern versions of TMUX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mouse mode is enabled, the `MouseDrag1Border` event is bound to `resize-pane -M` in the root key table. You can unbind this without disabling mouse mode with either

```
unbind-key -T root MouseDrag1Border
```

or

```
unbind-key -n MouseDrag1Border
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.